# When does a local Cohen–Macaulay ring admit a non-zero finitely generated maximal Cohen–Macaulay module of finite injective dimension?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, local-rings, cohen-macaulay-rings, injective-modules

Let $(R,\mathfrak m)$ be a local Cohen–Macaulay ring. Then, it is well- nown that there exists a non-zero finitely generated $R$-module of finite injective dimension; for instance $\operatorname{Hom}_R\left( \dfrac{R}{(x_1,\dotsc,x_d)R}, E_R(R/\mathfrak m)\right)$, where $x_1,\dotsc,x_d$ is a full system of parameters for $R$, and $E_R(-)$ denotes injective hull.

My question: Must $R$ also admit a non-zero finitely generated maximal Cohen–Macaulay module  of finite injective dimension?

The answer is yes if $R$ is complete as then $R$ admits a dualizing module. But what happens otherwise?